# Как реализовать класс, объекты которого хранят и выдают объекты разных типов в java?

Tags: ооп, java

У меня есть объекты разных классов(фигуры, например). Причем классы фигур наследуются от класса Figure. В свою очередь классы фигур(например Circle) имеют наследников(например PlasticCircle, PapperCircle..). Я хочу реализовать класс Box, куда методом put буду их класть, а методом get - получать(причем в get я передаю форму и материал фигур, которые хочу достать).

Пробовал сделать для каждого класса фигур по ArrayList-у, и перегружать метод put.

У меня вышло как-то так:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Box {
    protected ArrayList<PlasticCircle> listOfPlasticCircles;
    protected ArrayList<PapperCircle> listOfPapperCircles;
    // и так далее для всех фигур всех типов

    public Box(){
        listOfPlasticCircles = new ArrayList<PlasticCircle>();
        listOfPapperCircles = new ArrayList<PapperCircle>();
        //и так далее..
    }

    //Далее методы put(можно добавлять по несколько)
    public void put(PlasticCircle ... figures){
    for(PlasticCircle figure : figures){
        listOfPlasticCircles.add(figure);
    }
    }
//и так далее.
}
```

Но такой подход мне кажется слишком индусским. К тому же такой подход создает проблемы с расширяемостью, например, если я введу новый тип фигур. Пожалуйста, направьте на верный путь)

Comment: Может попробовать переменные с типом Object?

Comment: А как тогда обращаться к методам объектов?

Comment: В теле метода можно явно привести объект к нужному типу. В java есть оператор instanceOf, можно им воспользоваться для проверки типа объекта.

Comment: А почему бы не делать так:

1. В `Box` внутри просто `ArrayList<Circle>` или там `ArrayList<Figure>`
2. Метод `get` заменяется на метод фильтрации, который получает предикат, и возвращает все объекты из `Box`, удовлетворяющие предикату. При этом доступ к полям — проблема предиката. Предикат может быть простой (`o instanceof PlasticCircle`) или сложный (`o instanceof PlasticCircle && ((PlasticCircle)o).Color == RED`), об этом пускай ваш `Box` не заботится.

Великолепная расширяемость out of the box :-)

Answer (score 2):

Здесь очевидно вам нужен шаблон **Фабрика**

Comment: Так фабрика позволяет позволяет именно создавать иерархически не связанные объекты, а как этот паттерн поможет мне их хранить?

Comment: Фабрика позволяет создавать объекты, вызывая закрытый от вас конструктор этих объектов. Пусть фабрика создает фигуры. А хранить их надо в **ArrayList**. У всех фигур должен быть некий общий интерфейс, который необходимо вызывать в независимости от конкретной фигуры. Вы несите этот интерфейс в **Interface** или абстрактный класс. Сделайте **ArrayList<T>**, где **T** - созданный вами интерфейс. Тогда вы сможете обращаться к функциям и полям в любой фигуре. А для возможности вызова универсального конструктора - используйте шаблон **Фабричный метод**

Answer (score 1):

Серебряная пуля тут это фабричный метод. Вот [вики](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%28%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%29).

Коротко о главном:
Все объекты, которые могут быть возвращены реализуют один интерфейс и имеют одинаковый набор методов.

Comment: У меня Figure - абстрактный класс, в нем есть поле shape и метод area(). Далее Figure имеет наследников Circle, Square, Rectangle и Triangle. В свою очередь каждый класс определенной фигуры имеет наследников с префиксов Plastic и Papper, и классы с префиксов Plastic реализуют интерфейс Plastic, а классы с Papper - интерфейс Papper. Вот только мои классы не могут иметь одинаковый набор методов, так как бумажные фигуры можно, например, перекрашивать, а пластиковые - нет. А в коробку нужно пихать все.